# How can I accept a range in a Lua user command?

Tags: visual-mode, lua, vimscript-lua

I want to optionally accept a range in a user-defined function:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Pizzafy',
  function(args)
     if args.range > 0 then
        -- visual mode, I think
        print(args.line1 .. "-" .. args.line2 .. " pizzas")
     else
        -- normal or insert mode
        print("normal amount of pizzas")
     end
  end,
  { nargs = 0 }
)
```

But when I call this with a visual selection:

```
:'<,'>Pizzafy
```

I get an error: `E481: No range allowed`. How do I accept (and then parse out) the visual range in a Lua user command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Pizzafy',
  function(args)
     if args.range > 0 then
        -- visual mode, I think
        print(args.line1 .. "-" .. args.line2 .. " pizzas")
     else
        -- normal or insert mode
        print("normal amount of pizzas")
     end
  end,
  { nargs = 0, range = true }
)
```

You need to add the `range` option to allow the command to be used for ranges.